# How to make next / back button order accessible

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I am designing the UI for a checkout flow.  At the end of the page, I have 3 buttons, Next - Back - Canel.

On desktop it looks like 
(Back) (Next)
   Cancel

[image]

On mobile it looks like 
(Next)
(Back)
(Cancel)

[image]

In the code, its ordered Next back cancel then the placement manipulated through CSS.

The dev is saying because the visual order doesn't match the coded order it doesn't pass accessibility(on desktop). I don't wont to only have a stacked layout for both desktop and mobile, but do I have any other options?

Comment: It would be helpful to see some of your code

Comment: I’d put them in the right order for desktop, and rearrange it on mobile using flexbox’ `order`. (`order` and tabindex is a somewhat problematic thing - but on mobile the amount of users that actually navigate by “tabbing” should be rather small.)

Comment: @misorude I think this answers the question too, you could post it as such.

Comment: from what ive been told the way it's laid out on the screen must match the DOM order. So you cannot visually rearrange the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You could swap the placement of 'Back' and 'Next' on the desktop view. This way the visual layout would still match the source code order, without resorting to a stacked view.

Comment: true, however, the UX wouldn't be great as the button order would be opposite to user direction. Next should be on the right as the user would be moving forward and back on the left, going back if that makes sense